# Network only works after login?

Tags: networking, centos7, boot

I'm on linux academy RHCSA course and at the last test I have a VM that has to has its eth0 connection plugged off. So I turned it on with "nmcli con up eth0" and I went into "etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0" and set "ONBOOT" to "yes". But it only connects when I log in to the VM. I can't just turn on a VM with virt-manager and ssh from the host terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command.

`nmcli connection modify "System eth0" connection.autoconnect yes`

Then

```
nmcli connection down ; nmcli connection up
```